# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'textDecoration' of null fabricjs

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

**There is one issue I am facing while trying to load json using fabric.js.**
Code for how I am trying to load json on canvas:

```
response.json().then(function (data) {
          if ((typeof data.objects !== "undefined" && data.objects.length > 0) || 
              data.backgroundImage !== null || data.background !== null) {
            canvas.loadFromJSON(
              data,
              function () { 
                canvas.renderAll();
              },
              function (o, object) {
                console.log(o, object);
              }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! There is not enough information here to troubleshoot your issue. Please provide a working example of your code as either a snippet or jsfiddle/codepen that clearly demonstrates the issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you please share stackbliz/jsfiddle for editing